# Are SQLAlchemy model variables class or object type?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I am learning Web Development in Flask. I am using SQLAlchemy. A typical database object is structured like so:

```
class Role(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'roles'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64), unique=True)
    default = db.Column(db.Boolean, default=False, index=True)
    permissions = db.Column(db.Integer)
    users = db.relationship('User', backref='role', lazy='dynamic')

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Role %r>' % self.name
```

My question is, are these all class variables or object variables? They are outside the `__init__` so it would seem they are class variables, that seems odd though. Any pointers on this would be great! Thanks!

Comment: It looks different from regular Python class code, but those are indeed instance (object) variables.  Perhaps someone who knows Flask at a deeper level could give you more info about why that is.  My guess it that is has to do with the object's inheritance.

Answer (score 8):

The fields with type `Column` in `Role` are indeed class variables. But they would be replaced with `InstrumentedAttribute` during Role construction, which occurred in `declarative.aqi.DeclarativeMeta.__init__()`

This is why we define Role inherited from `Base` with metaclass `declarative.aqi.DeclarativeMeta` (the return value of [declarative_base()](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/extensions/declarative/api.html?highlight=declarativemeta))

The [`InstrumentedAttribute`](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/rel_1_1/orm/internals.html?highlight=instrumentedattribute#sqlalchemy.orm.attributes.InstrumentedAttribute) is a **data descriptor**, which defined `__get__` and `__set__` applied to instance dictionary. As a result, we could use them to do operation through instance.

In the following example, `r.name` is a data descriptor, `r.name = 'hello'` is equivalent to `Role.name.__set__(r, 'hello')` -> `r.__dict__['name'] = 'hello'`

```
r = Role()
r.name = 'hello'
```